# ng-change doesn't fire again after I change it's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in my HTML. Ignore any inline style, I'm testing,

```
<label class="toggle" style="float: right;">
  <input id="check" type="checkbox" ng-model="check" ng-change="funCheck(check)">
  <div class="track">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
</label>       

<div ng-init="fromClock='01:00'; toClock='03:30';">
  <clock-editor from="fromClock" to="toClock" 
                on-change="fromClock = from; toClock = to; funClock(from, to);"> 
  </clock-editor>                   
  <strong>{{fromClock}}</strong>
  <strong>{{toClock}}</strong>
</div>
```

That's a toggle radio button and a clock.

Then I have these two functions in my controller:

```
            $scope.funCheck = function(check) {                 
                alert(check);                   
            };

            $scope.funClock = function(f_from, f_to) {                  
                    console.log(f_from + "---" +f_to)
                    $scope.check = false;                               
                }               
            };
```

When the toggle is turned on I send the time from the clock somewhere. This works alright. However, what I want to do is **uncheck** the toggle if the time was changed.

I can do that with **document.getElementById('check').checked = false;** and the toggle moves back, but the *ng-change* on that radio won't fire again until I double check it. Like the value didn't change even if I can see how it's turned off visually.

Comment: Why are you using ng-model on <strong> ?

Comment: @Vivz as I said in my question, I'm testing. No reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using angular is the fact that you shouldn't have to edit the DOM manually like you're doing.

Change this part of your code which unchecks the checkbox

```
$scope.funClock = function(f_from, f_to) {                  
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked) {
        document.getElementById('check').checked = false;                                   
    }               
};
```

to

```
$scope.funClock = function(f_from, f_to) { 
    if($scope.check){
        $scope.check = false;
    }                          
};
```

Also, you shouldn't care about checking if it's already checked or not as if you set the checked to false and it's already false there will be no change so just remove the `if` statement completely.

**Edit**

Seems like `ng-change` will only fire if there is a change on the input itself and not if that change has happened programmatically, so there are two ways to do this.

1. Call the change function inside of the `funClock`.

This would be the code for that

```
$scope.funClock = function(f_from, f_to) { 
    if($scope.check){
        $scope.check = false;
        funCheck($scope.check);
    }                          
};
```

2. Add a watch for `check`.

Or the code for the watch

```
$scope.$watch('check', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue != oldValue) {
    funCheck(newValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, you're right about when to use JS, but since I'm new to angular I got obfuscated so I tried JS. I have an If because  there will be an else there soon. Also, I changed my code to what you adviced and it won't do it either.

Comment: Thanks again. $scope.check gives me undefined if I try to alert it. Doesn't matter if I check it or uncheck it, always undefined. I basically copied your code and added an alert.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` does not work on `strong` element and there is no `ng-change` event for `strong` element. So basically you can achieve this by using two watch variables like this, Hope this will help you.

```
        $watch(function(){
            return $scope.fromClock;
        }, function() {
            $scope.funCheck();
        })

        $watch(function(){
            return $scope.toClock;
        }, function() {
            $scope.funCheck();
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

In `angularjs` , we cann't directly change elements value. we need to 
use `$compile` . First include it in controller and then make use of 
it like wise -

```
var list = '<input id="check" type="checkbox" ng-model="check" checked ng-change="funCheck(check)">';

var selctr = $("#selector");
var ele = angular.element(list);
compiled = $compile(ele);
selctr.html(ele);
compiled($scope);
```